# Unordered horizontal list issue in IE6 + 7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I have an unordered list which displays fine in most browsers except for ie6+7. The problem is where i've styled the list items giving them a width and height and displaying them as a block so the have correct size. IE interprets the block and places the list items vertically rather then horizontally here is my code;

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NY94w/1/

HTML

```
<div>
     <ul class="hozlist">
          <li><a href="#" class="btnyellow ">View Details</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="btnyellow ">View NDP</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="btnyellow ">View News</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
ul.hozlist {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: left;
}
ul.hozlist li {display: inline-block; *display: inline}

    .btnyellow
    {
        width: 93px;
        height: 21px;
        background: yellow;      
        border:1px solid red;
        line-height:21px;
        vertical-align: middle;    
        padding: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 70%;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
    }
    a.btnyellow, a.btnyellowsmall{text-decoration: none;color: black;font-family: Arial;}
```

​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While A.K's answer would solve your problem, using float is not always the best solution. In case you do not want to float your elements you could add `zoom:1` to your `ul.hozlist li {}` rules set.

```
ul.hozlist li {display: inline-block; *display: inline; zoom:1;}
```

Comment: Thanks , the float threw the flow of my hmtl out so this worked better

Answer (score 0):

use `float:left` in the following instead of `display: inline-block; *display: inline`

```
ul.hozlist li {float: left}
```

### [SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/hfqtW/)

Answer (score 0):

> IE supports inline-block, but only for elements that are natively inline. So, if you really want to use inline-block, you’re restricted to spans and strongs and ems

Use `float:left` instead of `inline-block`:

```
ul.hozlist li {float: left;}
```